# <div> at the top of its container

Tags: html, css, positioning

I need a *div* to be positioned at the top inside its containing *div*, and leave unused space below itself. The default behavior seems to be the opposite, e.g. the contained *div* falls down to the floor of its containing *div* and leaves unused space above itself.

I assume that's quite a trivial thing to do, but I don't even know how to search for the solution on Google (tried "div float top", "div gravity" and some other meaningless searches...)

Here is my html code:

```
<div class="bonus">
  <div class="bonusbookmakerlogo">
    <a rel="nofollow" href="http://..." target="_blank"><img src="/img/box.png" alt="blah" title="blah"/></a>
  </div>
  <div class="bonustext">
    <span>Bonus description.</span>
  </div>
  <div class="bonusdivider"></div>
</div>
```

And relevant css:

```
.bonus {
  font-size: 90%;
  text-align: justify;
  margin: 1em 2em;
}

.bonusdivider {
  margin: 1em 0 1em 0;
  border: none;
  height: 1px;
  color: #999999; 
  background-color: #999999; 
}

.bonusbookmakerlogo {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20%;
}

.bonustext {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 70%;
}
```

The resulting layout is ok except the logo *div* (the one containing the *img* tag) that occupies the lower part of its containing *div* free space, while I need it to "fight" gravity and stay with its top edge hooked to the container top edge.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Please make a jsfiddle?

Comment: Sorry I didn't know about what jsfiddle is, now I've googled for it and found. I'm going to make it in a moment.

Comment: there http://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/6aEPw/ , logo is on top in your code. whats the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a slight modification using float instead of inline-block.
Seems to work OK:

```
<div class="bonus">
  <div class="bonusbookmakerlogo">
    <a rel="nofollow" href="http://..." target="_blank"><img src="/img/box.png" alt="blah" title="blah"/></a>
  </div>
  <div class="bonustext">
    <span>Bonus description.</span>
  </div>
  <div class="bonusdivider"></div>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
  .bonus {
    font-size: 90%;
    text-align: justify;
    margin: 1em 2em;
    height: 100px;
    border: 10px solid red; /* test */
  }

  .bonusdivider {
    margin: 1em 0 1em 0;
    border: none;
    height: 1px;
    color: #999999; 
    background-color: #999999; 
    clear: both;
  }

  .bonusbookmakerlogo {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
  }

  .bonustext {
    float: left;
    width: 70%;
  }
```

Comment: Inline block will sit at the base of the containing div. By floating instead, we solve the problem.

Comment: @Banana - notice carefully within the top div. The text in your case is at the base of the top div. Floating will position at the top.

Comment: op needs the logo img to stick to top of container. nothing is wrong with his code.

Comment: op maybe did not ask the question in the clearest possible manner. I've inferred from it that what he actually wants is for all contents within that div to remain at the top. @Lucio please clarify?

Comment: "The resulting layout is ok except the logo div (the one containing the img tag)" seems pretty clear to me...

Comment: Maybe, just not sure then what the question was about if the op did not think something was undesirable about his layout.

Comment: Ok thanks everybody for your help (thanks also to the 4 people who kindly downvoted a beginner's question... but that's another story). @Banana: http://jsfiddle.net/ec5c9/ see the problem? Marius George: thanks, I accept your answer also if I've found a different solution meanwhile: vertical-align: top;.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @Marius George works and I think it is the cleanest possible solution, but here his a different one I've found meanwhile:

```
.bonusbookmakerlogo {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20%;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```